# How do I getAs[Location]("location") from a dataframe row?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a class `Location(lat, lon)`, I created a dataframe `df = Seq(Location(1,2), Location(3,4)).toDF`. When I try to do this:

```
df.map(row => 
        row.getAs[Location]("location")
      )
```

it fails, because there's no encoder for `Location`. But how am I supposed to convert it into a `Dataset` of `Location`?

I tried:

```
df.map(row => 
        val seq = row.getAs[Seq[Int]]("location")
        Location(seq(0), seq(1))
      )
```

But it doesn't work either.

I am really confused. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Do you want to get Array of Locations or  Location type Dataset??

Comment: @Rao Dataset[Location].

Answer (score -1):

if you have `case class Location(lat: Int, lon: Int)` followed by `val df = Seq(Location(1,2), Location(3,4)).toDF` you could convert this dataframe `df` into a dataset or change that line to be `val ds = Seq(Location(1,2), Location(3,4)).toDS` where `ds` is `ds: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[Location] = [lat: int, lon: int]` which is what you said you wanted in one of the comments.